# select query for one-to-many relations table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have 2 tables. These two tables have one-to-many relations.

**TABLE - A**

```
column1 column2
1       label1
2       label2
```

**TABLE - B**

```
Bcolumn1 Bcolumn2 Bcolumn3
1        value1   value4
1        value2   value5
2        value3   value6
```

**RESULT TABLE**

```
column1 column2 json
1       label1  [[value1,value4],[value2,value5]]
2       label2  [[value3,value6]]
```

I want to get RESULT TABLE1 using TABLE - A and TABLE - B.

how can I get this result?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use  `group_concat` aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `GROUP_CONCAT` here:

```sql
SELECT
    a.column1,
    a.column2,
    '[' || GROUP_CONCAT('[' || b.Bcolumn2 || ',' || b.Bcolumn3 || ']') || ']' AS json
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON b.Bcolumn1 = a.column1
GROUP BY
    a.column1,
    a.column2;
```

### Demo